# Show errors in login form

Tags: python, django, django-messages

I've created a user login page, and it works great! But when the user inputs the wrong credentials, how can I show an error on the login page? I tried usign an if and a variable, but that resulted in the error being shown no matter what.

In my views, I've set the "error_message" variable like so:

```
def LoginView(request):
    error_message = ''
    logout(request)
    context = RequestContext(request)
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
        else:
            # Return a 'disabled account' error message
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message
  --->  error_message = "Incorrect username or password."
    return render(request, 'profile/login.html', {'error_message': error_message}, context)
```

However, in my template, this variable is displayed no matter what, even if I set the variable inside the "if" statement.

Here's my template:

```
{% include '__header.html' %}
<style>
main {
    width: 920px;
    background: none;
    margin-top: calc(50vh - 280px)
}
</style>

<div class="form-container">
<form id="user" method="post" action="/login/" 
enctype="multipart/form-data" class="text">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="title">Login to your account</div>
    <div class="form-col">
        <div class="field-container">
            <div class="field-input-container">
                <div class="field-label">Username</div>
                <div class="field-input">
                    <input class="field-input-element" type="text" name="username"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="field-help"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-col">
        <div class="field-container" style="height: 110px">
            <div class="field-input-container">
                <div class="field-label">Password</div>
                <div class="field-input">
                <input class="field-input-element" type="password" name="password"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="field-error">{{ error_message }}</div>
        <div class="field-help"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-button-container">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="button form-button"/>
    </div>
</form> 
</div>

{% include '__footer.html' %}
```

So, how can I show an error message in the template only if there has been an error?

---

Updated code based off answers (still does same thing)

```
def LoginView(request):
    template_name='profile/login.html'
    logout(request)
    context = RequestContext(request)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
            else:
                # Return a 'disabled account' error message
                return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
        else:
            # Return an 'invalid login' error message
            error_message = "Incorrect username or password."
    else:
        error_message = ''

    return render(request, 'profile/login.html', {'error_message': error_message}, context)
```

Comment: Why not use the [login view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.login)?

Comment: I want more control over what the view actually does, and this works perfectly. I'm not going to go screw around trying to make something else work when this works fine.

Comment: For what its worth, there really isn't much that needs doing to use the django one, that link I provided even gives you an example template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic that you have for checking the users details should only be done if they've posted the form so you can wrap this part in an `if request.method == 'POST'`

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
        else:
            # Return a 'disabled account' error message
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message
        error_message = "Incorrect username or password."
```

You might also want to wrap your error div in a

```
{% if error_message %}
```

Comment: It's doing the same thing.

Comment: @SebastianOlsen - Could you update your current question to also include what you've updated it to? I can't see how it could be

Comment: Actually, nevermind! It's not doing the same thing anymore. My browser was caching the page for some reason after I refreshed. It works!

Comment: @SebastianOlsen - Ah of course, [should i blame caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate problem is that you are setting your error message for GET and POST requests. You should only show it for POST requests, after the user has submitted data.

```
if request.method == "POST":
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        ...
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message
        error_message = "Incorrect username or password."
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that could be useful for you, first import and inside your view declare a template name  :

```
from django.contrib import messages

template_name='your_app/login.html' #Inside the login view
```

Then, after login fails :

```
messages.error(request, "incorrect user or password")
```

And last, render the template :

```
return render(request, self.template_name,{"form_group" : form_group})
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: "self" is not defined. Also, I would like to add that I am not using a Form, I'm just getting the info from the HTML Form and then posting it to the server with the correct fields.

Comment: I see, Self would be the view where you put the login code, form code in render is just a parameter i put there just in case you were using forms or if yopu wanted to return the wrong values to the user

Comment: @jsanchezs - even though the function name was LoginView, it was still a function based view, not a class based view which is what your answer is designed for